# URL's length limit in httr::GET

Tags: r, httr

I am using `httr::GET` to query a local instance of OSRM,  an open source routing machine. The requests are made of thousands of points' coordinates and can be very long (40k-50k characters). When a requests is up to around 30k characters, `GET` works and fetches the results. When the request is bigger, `GET` gets stuck. Please note that the same long request works if I copy and paste it in Firefox or Chrome, so it shouldn't be an issue on the server side.

Edit: the same problem arises with `RCurl::getURL` with a slightly higher size limit.

Is this a `httr` issue or limit? Can I get around it?